# adding return case to recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

When it comes to recursion, here is where I struggle, I know the edge case for when the function should be true, but because I have to add a return false statement as well, and somewhere deep in the call stack, it does become true(which is the whole point of examining!), I want the final outcome to be true, and for the recursion to stop. But eventually, it finds its way to the return false, simply because its the last thing the function does.

```
public boolean isPathHelper(Node node, String input){
    if(node.accept == true){
        return true;
    }else{
        if(input.length() == 0){
            return false;
        }
        isPathHelper(getNextState(node, input.charAt(0) -'0'), input.substring(1));
        return false;
    }
```

How do I deal with this scenario? I know global variables can help, but I was hoping there's a gap in my knowledge instead.

Comment: I think you might want something like `else { return isPathHelper(); }` instead of the method call then a return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean isPathHelper(Node node, String input, int count){
    if(input.length() == 0){
        return false; //I can't go any further: return "failed"
    }
    else if(count == input.length()){
        return true; //if I ever reach here, then I am done: return "success"
    }
    // else call self recursively
    return isPathHelper(
      getNextState(node, input.charAt(0) -'0'), input.substring(1), count+1);
}
```

Just examine your logic and your data carefully enough to be *SURE* you hit "count == input.length()" at some point.  Preferably at some point before you run out of stack ;)

Comment: But how do I know that it failed?

Comment: let me add some more details to the question

Comment: Q: The criteria for "success" is "count == input.length()", correct?  Q: What's the criteria for "failed"?

Comment: please take a look at what I have now, that might help

Comment: I've updated my reply.  You must explicitly check for each "terminal condition".  Otherwise, keep recursing.  It's up to you to decide exactly what the "terminal conditions: are, and verify they're each expressed "correctly".  For example, maybe it should be ">=" instead of "==". Or "input.length() - 1". 'Hope that helps...

Comment: so once it hits count == input.length() and it returns true, then what happens to the remaining stack calls?